# Automtically resizing custom kivy widget

Tags: python, kivy

I just discovered kivy and decided to give it a try as the GUI framework for my next software project. I worked through the tutorials and now would like to create my own widget. However, I have some trouble getting the widget to resize properly. Here is a minimal (non-)working example:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.layout import Layout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle


class TestWidget(Layout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(0,0), size=(1,1))
        self.bind(pos=self.update)
        self.bind(size=self.update)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return TestWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I expected this to display a white window, where the white rectangle resizes with the window. However, the size is only set correctly once at startup and and the `update` method is never called again. What am I doing wrong?

I found working examples here on StackOverflow, but they all use the kv language which I would like to avoid (there must be a way to get it to work without kv language...).

Edit: I'm running kivy 1.9.0, pygame 1.9.2a0 and Python 3.4.1 on Linux

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems correct and it works fine here. Also, I don't recommend avoiding kv, though indeed you don't have to use it.

Comment: In this example I tried avoiding kv to understand how kivy works internally. I already suspected this to be a problem with my setup. Could you please tell me which Python version and version of kivy you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution. It seems to be a pygame problem. I now forced kivy to use SDL2 and it works flawlessly.